# Windows computer freezes only when is connected to the internet

Tags: windows, hard-drive, wireless-networking, audio, freeze

Asus Zenbook 10GB RAM, Intel CPU, SSD, Windows 10

**What's happening ?**

When connected to internet wirelessly and doing some more heavy stuff like Youtube, Torrent download, Google Maps or just simply browsing pages with lot's of JS my PC started to freeze

**What means freeze ?**

Everything reacts super slow, even cursor is moving very laggy and in case I listen music (doesn't matted if from youtube or hdd) I even hear laggy distorted digital sounds...

The problem is, that after "heavy task" everything gets back to normal instantly. When I'm disconnected, I can do anything, even edit large videos no problem.

Despite it might looks like some crappy virus or so, I'm sure is not. I wiped out computer several times, tried Win 7, Win 8, Win 10, nothing helps. Also task manager shows CPU and RAM in normal values. Also I've made disk check, no bad sectors.

I am pretty much sure that this must be only faliure of HW, but have no idea what might cause this.
I would suspect Wireless adapter, but I've tried to make USB hotspot with my Android and it was the same.

Please help me get out that problem. Thank you!

Comment: It could be a swap file problem: inadequate size or highly fragmented. Your internet applications could be using lots of virtual memory: check with Task Manager for high memory use.

Comment: This sounds interesting, but Task Manager doesn't show high memory usage. From my 10gb is 6 used even when downloading torrent and pc keeps frezzing

Answer (score 0):

First would you check this setting:

Press and hold the Windows button ( lower left corner )

Choose Device Manger

Click on the network adapter to expand the list

Right click on the adapter and choose properties

Click the power management tab

if "allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" is    checked please remove it and  press OK

Repeat this procedure for any additional network adapters listed.

Comment: Thank you, but sadly it did not helped. PC still remains freezing after heavy internet tasks